# Keep first zero in text input filled by getElementById

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
$bins2 = sqlsrv_get_field( $bins, 0);
echo $bins2;

echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
   document.getElementById('bin_code').value = $bins2;
</script>
";
```

The above code gets a value ($bins2) from a SQL Server query.

The `echo $bins2;` shows a result of 0119

When using the JS code and fill the html TEXT input, it gets filled as 119 instead 0f 0119.

How can I avoid the first zero being removed?
The input is text, so it may also contain letters sometimes.

This is the input that is filled:

```
<input type="text" name="bin_code" id="bin_code" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $bin;?>">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The input is text, so it may also contain letters sometimes.

Text values need quotes around them:

```
document.getElementById('bin_code').value = '$bins2';
```

JavaScript doesn't know where the value came from or anything about the PHP code, all it sees is the literal value on the page.  If that value is a string, it needs to be wrapped in quotes.